# Running a .config file on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to run a custom .config file on my elastic beanstalk. I'm following the directions on [this link](http://www.tonmoygoswami.com/2013/05/how-to-enable-gzip-on-amazon-elastic.html). I've created a file called `myapp.config`, and put the following in it:

```
container_commands:
        01_setup_apache:
        command: "cp .ebextensions/enable_mod_deflate.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_deflate.conf"
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> "commands" in configuration file .ebextensions/myapp.config in application version myapp-0.0.33-SNAPSHOT must be a map. Update "commands" in the configuration file.

This error is really cryptic. What am I doing wrong?

My container is apache tomcat 7.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Got the answer. Apparently whitespace is important. I changed:

```
container_commands:
        01_setup_apache:
        command: "cp .ebextensions/enable_mod_deflate.conf 
/etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_deflate.conf"
```

to:

```
container_commands:
        01_setup_apache:
            command: "cp .ebextensions/enable_mod_deflate.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_deflate.conf"
```

and now it works.

Comment: Spaces are important in YAML.

Answer (score 1):

The config file formats can be either **yaml** or **json**. Your original config was of yaml style but non-conformant. That is why **fixing white space** (which is making it yaml compliant) fixed your config. If you are writing your config in yaml, you can run it through a yaml parser to check if it is compliant.