# Elastic Beanstalk ebextension config files using VS toolkit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Im trying to set Folder Permissions for creating additional folders/files inside Temp directory in my .Net Project. 
I know there a lot of references for a similar question like this (as given)

[Running a .config file on Elastic Beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148417/running-a-config-file-on-elastic-beanstalk?rq=1)

[How To Set Folder Permissions in Elastic Beanstalk Using YAML File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621421/how-to-set-folder-permissions-in-elastic-beanstalk-using-yaml-file)

Im having trouble verifying if its given the permission, im not able to create any folders/files in the Temp folder; i cant find any errors either during deployment in the Elastic Beanstalk (last 100 lines) related to permission setting.
Im using the following code in my config file

command: icacls \"C:/inetpub/wwwroot/myapp_deploy/Temp\" /grant DefaultAppPool:(OI)(CI)

(i have replaced myapp with the EB application name)

Please help anyone.

Comment: it's unclear what is the error you're getting or what config file you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

i was having trouble posting the code and a general unknown exception error was being generated with no additional details.

Figured out the mistake i was making:

1. ICACLS command requires the directory path to have double slash '\'.
   Verified command for above would be:

command: "icacls \"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Temp\" /grant DefaultAppPool:(OI)(CI)F"